# Facebook SDK NSURLErrorDomain Error

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, nsurlerrordomain

I'm trying to implement Facebook Login (and LinkedIn next) into my app and am running into troubles with getting the user information. I've got the login button setup and working, and it will correctly transition to the home page if the user is already logged in -- great, all working. Now, I need to fetch the user's actual data out of Facebook.

I'm trying to use the FBSDKGraphRequest API for this. Right now I've got this very simple code to just try to get it up and running:

```
func getUserData() {
    print("starting user data fetch")
    let parameters = ["fields": "last_name"]
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/{user-id}", parameters: parameters)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, user, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            if let userId = user.lastName {
                print("\(userId)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is populating the error variable in the block with the following:

```
domain: NSURLErrorDomain  code: 18446744073709550614
```

I've searched all up and down the internet, and this error code doesn't appear anywhere. No errors are logged to the console, it is only evident in the variable inspector when I hit my breakpoint.

I'm very new to the FBSDK, so if you need any more info let me know and I can provide it for you!

Comment: Stupid question, am I right in assuming that you replaced `{user-id}` with a real user-id or `me`?

Comment: Not stupid, but I guess that's my error right there. Like I said, this is my first go around with it, I thought you entered a path for it. I'll try it with me or the user-I'd tonight and will proceed to feel stupid if that is what makes it work haha